# Cannot link against cmake imported targets

Tags: boost, cmake

I am trying to compile a project with a large code base and (possibly) not fully up-to-date `CMakeLists.txt`. The software has several components. In particular you separately build core of the application and then proceed to build various extensions. The core also uses boost as one of its many dependencies.

I successfully configured and built the core component. I am now building the GUI extension. Configure is successful but `make` fails whilst linking against boost with the following errors:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lBoost::filesystem
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lBoost::system
```

I can fix this by *manually* invoking `gcc` with `-lBoost::filesystem` replaced by`-lboost_filesystem`.

Clearly something went wrong with the configuration. When I inspect the variables with `ccmake` I can confirm that cmake is pointing to the right boost directory. After investigating `CMakeLists.txt` I found that `${Boost_FILESYSTEM_LIBRARY}` is referenced in the core source code, but not in extension e.g.

```
SET(COMMON_LIBS
  Registry
  ...
  ${Boost_FILESYSTEM_LIBRARY}
  ${Boost_SYSTEM_LIBRARY}
)
...
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(Launcher ResourcesManager ${LIBBATCH_LIBRARIES} ${LIBXML2_LIBS} ${Boost_FILESYSTEM_LIBRARY} ${Boost_SYSTEM_LIBRARY})
...
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(SalomeLauncher Launcher ${COMMON_LIBS})
```

Could you please point me in the right direction? In particular do problem like this indicate issues with Boost, with the application kernel or with application extension? Any hint at this stage would be useful.

## Motivation and setup

I am trying to compile [SALOME](https://www.salome-platform.org/user-section/about/mesh) on Arch Linux with `cmake` version 3.17.1.

Comment: Can you please show the code in your question post? Specifically, the section in which `-lBoost::filesystem` is used? This looks incorrect: `Boost::filesystem` is an imported CMake target, and can be used in `target_link_libraries` calls by itself, and the `-l` link flag is typically not necessary in CMake files. Please refer to the examples on [this](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindBoost.html) page in the CMake documentation.

Comment: @squareskittles thanks for a quick reply. I am aware of how targets can be put in `target_link_libraries`. What code would you like to see? `CMakeLists.txt`?

Comment: I think I understood what you meant. I am not changing `CMakeLists.txt`. I made the manual replacement in `gcc` invocation and rerun only the failing link command. Elaborated this in the quetsion now.

Comment: Sorry, I meant it would be helpful to see the CMake code, specifically the section of CMake code where the filesystem library gets linked.

Comment: Done. I included a relevant passage in the description. Please let me know.

Comment: Ok, to debug this further, it would be useful to know what `Boost_FILESYSTEM_LIBRARY` is defined as in the CMake code. Can you add this portion of the code as well, or, you can print its contents by adding `message(${Boost_FILESYSTEM_LIBRARY})` to your CMake file.

Comment: We may end up having a long discussion here if we pursue this. Maybe it's more appropriate for the mailing list? I can debug with print statements, but I am wondering if there's anything large I am missing. Maybe the extension doesn't pick up the cmake config file somehow?

Comment: Yes. It appears to be saying `Boost::filesystem` even when I configure the core so at least it's consistent.

Comment: "Maybe it's more appropriate for the mailing list?" - Yes, it is better to ask developers about the building problem. We could only guess what their code actually does and what it is intended to do. BTW, their `CMakeLists.txt` is marked with 2.8.8 CMake version. In this version CMake even doesn't warn about not existed IMPORTED target `Boost::filesystem` and passes it to the linker as a plain library name.

Comment: It is hard to know what it going on throughout the project without seeing more of the code, or a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

I am going to post a less manual solution in case anyone comes across it and cannot fix their `CMakeLists.txt`. I ended up using `sed` to automate this build:

```
cmake \
  -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release \
  ...
  ../ \
  && find -name link.txt -exec sed -i \
    -e 's/Boost::filesystem/boost_filesystem/' \
    -e 's/Boost::system/boost_system/' {} \; \
  && make -j && make install
```

This should obviously not be necessary, but if cannot debug your build systems, it should work.